# Copy-Item recursive by string

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy-item

I would like to use Copy-Item to recursively copy all files that contain *CBB* and move it to another location. I have tried the following below, it did not error out however it did nothing either.

```
Copy-Item -path c:\users\user1\ -Recurse -Include *CBB* -Destination c:\users\user1\newfolder
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy files whose CONTENT contains the string "CBB"?  Or do you want to copy files where the FILENAME contains the string "CBB"?  Additionally, do your target files have a particular file extension?

Comment: The file names contain CBB and yes they all have the ext of xls however so do all the other files that do not contain CBB in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may do the trick for you.  I find the `Include` and `Exclude` on `Copy-Item` to be a little finicky, so I used `Where-Object` instead.

Also, note that I'm excluding files that contain the filename `newfolder`.  This is because your destination directory is in the same directory where you're searching and copying from which can cause errors.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\users\user1\' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*CBB*" -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'newfolder' } | Copy-Item -Destination 'c:\users\user1\newfolder'
```

Comment: I am getting an error of unexpected token "-not" in expression or statement.

Comment: @ThisGuyUsesPowershell Sorry about that! I had a line break in the wrong place when I copied the code.  I've fixed it, could you please retry?